# Adding custom "styles" to Paperclip gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Right now I have this

```
has_attached_file :cover_image,
                   styles: { square: "200x200#", small:"400x400>",medium:"500x600" }
```

I want to have this:

```
has_attached_file :cover_image,
                   styles: { thumb: "50x50#", square: "200x200#", small: "400x400>", medium: "500x600" }
```

When I add the "thumb" key I get a 404 error. Is there a way to create a new "style"?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is no issue in your code.

You might be getting error while fetching previous record's thumb, which is not generated yet. Try create previous record thumbnail also and your error will gone.

Run below command in console.

```
rake paperclip:refresh CLASS=User ## change User with model name.
```

More information you can find [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Thumbnail-Generation).

Comment: Thanks @Dipak, but that didn't work form. I also tried 
`rake paperclip:refresh:thumbnails CLASS=User`

Comment: Can you update your console logs in question? It will help in find solution

Comment: This here: 

`GET http://localhost:3000/system/development/storage/templates/3/cover_images/thumbnails/ax8jlb16ldc-ian-schneider.jpg?1488540734 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: You are not fetching image properly. You are calling like `<%= image_tag @template.cover_image.url(:thumbn‌​ail) %>` try change it to `<%= image_tag @template.cover_image.url(:thumb) %>` My assumption on basis of logs.